# ¿Cómo convertir de javascript a jQuery, animación de chat whatsapp?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Tengo una simulación de chat contacto de WhatsApp como puedo reemplazar el código javascript a la versión de jQuery 3.3.1, de la manera más sencilla y simple.

El 100% de mi sitio tiene ejemplos y animaciones sencillas con jQuery en un solo archivo app.js por lo que no quiero usar otro archivo que no sea solo de jQuery.

¿Me podrían explicar como realizar los cambios?

Le adjunto el código completo en formato javascript funcionando todo correctamente:

```js
popupWhatsApp = () => {
  
  let btnClosePopup = document.querySelector('.closePopup');
  let btnOpenPopup = document.querySelector('.whatsapp-button');
  let popup = document.querySelector('.popup-whatsapp');
  let sendBtn = document.getElementById('send-btn');

  btnClosePopup.addEventListener("click",  () => {
    popup.classList.toggle('is-active-whatsapp-popup')
  })
  
  btnOpenPopup.addEventListener("click",  () => {
    popup.classList.toggle('is-active-whatsapp-popup')
     popup.style.animation = "fadeIn .6s 0.0s both";
  })
  
  sendBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let msg = document.getElementById('whats-in').value;
  let relmsg = msg.replace(/ /g,"%20");
    //just change the numbers "1515551234567" for your number. Don't use +001-(555)1234567     
   window.open('https://wa.me/15551234567?text='+relmsg, '_blank'); 
  
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    popup.classList.toggle('is-active-whatsapp-popup');
  }, 3000);
}

popupWhatsApp();
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
/* offset-x > | offset-y ^| blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.45);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.pulse {
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  animation-name: pulse;
}

.nav-bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-content: flex-end;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 8;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .nav-bottom {
    width: 320px;
  }
}

.whatsapp-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 8;
  transition: .3s;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 7px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  /* offset-x > | offset-y ^| blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
}

.circle-anime {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .3s;
  background-color: #77bb4a;
  animation: pulse 1.2s 4.0s ease 4;
}

.popup-whatsapp {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  bottom: 85px;
  right: 6px;
  transition: .5s;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  /* offset-x > | offset-y ^| blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  animation: slideInRight .6s 0.0s both;
}
.popup-whatsapp > div {
  margin: 5px;
}
@media (max-width: 680px) {
  .popup-whatsapp p {
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }
}
.popup-whatsapp > .content-whatsapp.-top {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.popup-whatsapp > .content-whatsapp.-top p {
  color: #585858;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.0em;
}
.popup-whatsapp > .content-whatsapp.-bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.closePopup {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f76060;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
}
.closePopup:hover {
  background-color: #f71d1d;
  transition: .3s;
}

.send-msPopup {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
}
.send-msPopup:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  transition: .3s;
}

.is-active-whatsapp-popup {
  display: flex;
  animation: slideInRight .6s 0.0s both;
}

input.whats-input[type=text] {
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  transition: .3s;
}
@media (max-width: 420px) {
  input.whats-input[type=text] {
    width: 225px;
  }
}
input.whats-input::placeholder {
  /* Most modern browsers support this now. */
  color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  opacity: 1;
}
input.whats-input[type=text]:focus {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s;
}

.icon-whatsapp-small {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.icon-whatsapp {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}

.icon-font-color {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.icon-font-color--black {
  color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<div class="nav-bottom">
            <div class="popup-whatsapp fadeIn">
                <div class="content-whatsapp -top"><button type="button" class="closePopup">
                      <i class="material-icons icon-font-color">close</i>
                    </button>
                    <p>Hello,  need help?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="content-whatsapp -bottom">
                  <input class="whats-input" id="whats-in" type="text" Placeholder="Send message..." />
                    <button class="send-msPopup" id="send-btn" type="button">
                        <i class="material-icons icon-font-color--black">send</i>
                    </button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" id="whats-openPopup" class="whatsapp-button">
                <img class="icon-whatsapp" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/134/134937.svg">
            </button>
            <div class="circle-anime"></div>
        </div>
```

No tengo más detalles que agregar el sistema de stackoverflow no me deja publicar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te adjunto el código en jquery, en realidad es muy muy similar el código que tienes, únicamente modificar los cambios que afectan al dom.

- document.querySelector, lo cambias por el selector de jquery $().
- addEventListener, se cambia por.
  .click(function (){}) ó por .on("click", function(){})
- classList.toggle , lo modificas por .toggleClass('clase');

Eso es prácticamente los cambios para JQuery, el resto es javascript, que no tienen interpretación en JQuery, dado que es para manipular el Dom.

```js
popupWhatsApp = () => {
  
  let btnClosePopup = $('.closePopup');
  let btnOpenPopup = $('.whatsapp-button');
  let popup = $('.popup-whatsapp');
  let sendBtn = $('send-btn');

  btnClosePopup.on("click",  () => {
    popup.toggleClass('is-active-whatsapp-popup');
  })
  
  btnOpenPopup.on("click",  () => {
    popup.toggleClass('is-active-whatsapp-popup');
    popup.css("animation","fadeIn .6s 0.0s both");
  })
  
  sendBtn.on("click", () => {
    let msg = $('whats-in').val();
    let relmsg = msg.replace(/ /g,"%20");
    //just change the numbers "1515551234567" for your number. Don't use +001-(555)1234567     
    window.open('https://wa.me/15551234567?text='+relmsg, '_blank'); 
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    popup.toggleClass('is-active-whatsapp-popup');
  }, 3000);
}

popupWhatsApp();
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
/* offset-x > | offset-y ^| blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.45);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.pulse {
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  animation-name: pulse;
}

.nav-bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-content: flex-end;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 8;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .nav-bottom {
    width: 320px;
  }
}

.whatsapp-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 8;
  transition: .3s;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 7px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  /* offset-x > | offset-y ^| blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
}

.circle-anime {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .3s;
  background-color: #77bb4a;
  animation: pulse 1.2s 4.0s ease 4;
}

.popup-whatsapp {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  bottom: 85px;
  right: 6px;
  transition: .5s;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  /* offset-x > | offset-y ^| blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  animation: slideInRight .6s 0.0s both;
}
.popup-whatsapp > div {
  margin: 5px;
}
@media (max-width: 680px) {
  .popup-whatsapp p {
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }
}
.popup-whatsapp > .content-whatsapp.-top {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.popup-whatsapp > .content-whatsapp.-top p {
  color: #585858;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.0em;
}
.popup-whatsapp > .content-whatsapp.-bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.closePopup {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f76060;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
}
.closePopup:hover {
  background-color: #f71d1d;
  transition: .3s;
}

.send-msPopup {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
}
.send-msPopup:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  transition: .3s;
}

.is-active-whatsapp-popup {
  display: flex;
  animation: slideInRight .6s 0.0s both;
}

input.whats-input[type=text] {
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  transition: .3s;
}
@media (max-width: 420px) {
  input.whats-input[type=text] {
    width: 225px;
  }
}
input.whats-input::placeholder {
  /* Most modern browsers support this now. */
  color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.705);
  opacity: 1;
}
input.whats-input[type=text]:focus {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s;
}

.icon-whatsapp-small {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.icon-whatsapp {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}

.icon-font-color {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.icon-font-color--black {
  color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<div class="nav-bottom">
            <div class="popup-whatsapp fadeIn">
                <div class="content-whatsapp -top"><button type="button" class="closePopup">
                      <i class="material-icons icon-font-color">close</i>
                    </button>
                    <p>Hello,  need help?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="content-whatsapp -bottom">
                  <input class="whats-input" id="whats-in" type="text" Placeholder="Send message..." />
                    <button class="send-msPopup" id="send-btn" type="button">
                        <i class="material-icons icon-font-color--black">send</i>
                    </button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" id="whats-openPopup" class="whatsapp-button">
                <img class="icon-whatsapp" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/134/134937.svg">
            </button>
            <div class="circle-anime"></div>
        </div>
```